# Finding the k-th largest number in a vector recursively

Tags: recursion

I have an unsorted vector and i want to return the k-th largest number in this vector recursively. There is a way to do this?

Ex: 2 3 41 67 0 9

And I want to return the second largest number which is 41.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com.
Please have a look at the about page. You should usually show your own approach or solution first ("show your work") and ask why it does not work, instead of letting the community solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

search for the highest number in the vector, remove it from the vector, repeat *k* times.

In pseudo-code:

```
function findKthHighestNumber(vetor, k):
  i := findIndexOfHighestNumber(vector)
  if k = 1:
    return vector[i]
  else
    return findKthHighestNumber(concat(vector[0..i-1], vector[i+1..vector.length]), k-1)
```

Of course, the actual implementation would depend on the programming language used. Also, `findIndexOfHighestNumber` should be provided as well, but that's a different task ...

Comment: This is just iteration, not recursion.

Comment: ok, I might have been a bit short. Added pseudo-code to demonstrate. This shows how it is recursive.

Answer (score 0):

You use a helper like

```
(define (nth-max vec nth cur-idx cur-max  lower-than)
   ...)
```

or the same as named let. The logic in it should:

1. If cur-idx is same as vector-length 
    A. nth is larger than 1: recur with lower-than as cur-max and reduce nth by 1 and set cur-idx to 0.
    B. Else cur-max is the solution.
2. Recur with cur-idx as cur-max if it's higher than cur-max and lower than lower-than

You can start off lower-than as +Inf.0 and cur-max as first element as -Inf.0. If the result is -Inf.0 then there is no solution.. eg. Find second largest in #(5 5 5 5)